# Codemirror - color a line based in a tag

Tags: codemirror

We've a file with a log file style log4j

```
[                main] [DEBUG] (14:25:46.832 CET) server started
[                main] [ INFO] (14:25:46.832 CET) I'm a nice info line
[                main] [ERROR] (14:25:46.832 CET) wrong user password for user '..'
```

Each line depending on if it's a DEBUG, INFO or ERROR should be colored in a different way (the whole line)

How this be done with Codemirror ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the defineSimpleMode is straight forward using a regular expression :

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("log4j",
    {
        start: [
            {regex: /.*\[FATAL\].*/, token: "log4j-fatal"},
            {regex: /.*\[ERROR\].*/, token: "log4j-error"},
            {regex: /.*\[ WARN\].*/, token: "log4j-warn"},
            {regex: /.*\[ INFO\].*/, token: "log4j-info"},
            {regex: /.*\[DEBUG\].*/, token: "log4j-debug"},
            {regex: /.*\[TRACE\].*/, token: "log4j-trace"},
        ],
    });
```